# How to migrate users in SoftEther from one server to another?

Tags: users, migration

I'm using SoftEther as a VPN server system and it works fine for me.  But was wondering how (if its possible) to move users from one server to another without having to recreate the account?

I can't find where the user data is stored and I'm not using any real storage for authentication (community version doesn't have that support yet), so I'm using its own database.

None of the commands in vpncmd seem to do what I want either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoftEther configuration, including the list of users, is stored in `vpn_server.config` in the installation directory. You could probably copy the `UserList` section from this file (note that there may be more then one of this section).

Comment: Thanks. :)  I'll check itout.  I've also found another way using Pexpect to make it possible as well.  Though hopefully I'll be able to pull more data from this file.

Comment: This might help too: https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/3._SoftEther_VPN_Server_Manual/3.3_VPN_Server_Administration#Transferring_the_Configuration_File_to_Another_Computer